# How do I stop the copy range using VBA?

Tags: vba, copy-paste

How do I disable the copy range using VBA after the copy/paste Sub is run?
Application.CutCopyMode = False does not work. The copy range is still selected and will paste in any cell if the enter button is pressed.

Comment: Can you show the part of the code that does the copy and paste and the Application.CutCopyMode?

Comment: "False - Cancels Cut or Copy mode and removes the moving border."  Setting to False does not de-select the currently-selected range, but it should remove the "paste" option...

Comment: Consider switching to a method that doesn't use cutcopy mode like `Range.Copy Destination:=Range2` Or `Range2.Value = Range1.Value`.

Comment: Also, is the [ants] tag correct here? Are you using .Net or VBA?

Comment: @Toddleson - guessing "marching ants" = the border around a copied range before pasting elsewhere